# rolling sum by group

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this simple example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : [pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01'), 
                             pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01'), 
                             pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01'), 
                             pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01')],
                   'group' : ['a','a','b','b'],
                   'value' : [1,2,3,4],
                   'value_useless' : [2,2,2,2]})

df
Out[78]: 
        date group  value  value_useless
0 2018-01-01     a      1              2
1 2018-01-01     a      2              2
2 2018-01-01     b      3              2
3 2018-01-01     b      4              2
```

Here I want to compute the rolling sum of `value` by group. I try the simple

```
df['rolling_sum'] = df.groupby('group').value.rolling(2).sum()
TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

A variant with `apply` does not seem to work either

```
df['rolling_sum'] = df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: x.value.rolling(2).sum())
TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

What am I missing here? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `groupby` is adding an index level that is getting in your way.

```
rs = df.groupby('group').value.rolling(2).sum()
df.assign(rolling_sum=rs.reset_index(level=0, drop=True))

        date group  value  value_useless  rolling_sum
0 2018-01-01     a      1              2          NaN
1 2018-01-01     a      2              2          3.0
2 2018-01-01     b      3              2          NaN
3 2018-01-01     b      4              2          7.0
```

#### details

```
rs

# Annoying Index Level
# |
# v
# group   
# a      0    NaN
#        1    3.0
# b      2    NaN
#        3    7.0
# Name: value, dtype: float64
```

---

Alternatively, you can get around the added index by using `pd.concat`

```
df.assign(rolling_sum=pd.concat(s.rolling(2).sum() for _, s in df.groupby('group').value))

        date group  value  value_useless  rolling_sum
0 2018-01-01     a      1              2          NaN
1 2018-01-01     a      2              2          3.0
2 2018-01-01     b      3              2          NaN
3 2018-01-01     b      4              2          7.0
```