# How to iteratively sum elements of one column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am a novice. I have a dataframe that contains annual 5 min resolution electricity load data for 100 consumers (each csv has >100,000 lines). For a particular customer, I need to find a rolling maximum half hourly  demand for each month. As my data is for every 5 minutes, I am aggregating 6 entries in the column load power (kW) successively

```
ID  Date_time   load power (kW)
0   1/01/2018 0:00  0.191566105
1   1/01/2018 0:05  0.193145833
2   1/01/2018 0:10  0.192853152
3   1/01/2018 0:15  0.270974475
4   1/01/2018 0:20  0.290183338
5   1/01/2018 0:25  0.185485805
6   1/01/2018 0:30  0.208431765
7   1/01/2018 0:35  0.269577658
8   1/01/2018 0:40  0.268412758
9   1/01/2018 0:45  0.286095837
10  1/01/2018 0:50  0.301008341
11  1/01/2018 0:55  0.390496602
12  1/01/2018 1:00  0.406787652
13  1/01/2018 1:05  0.229862502
14  1/01/2018 1:10  0.190870833
15  1/01/2018 1:15  0.190224999
```

load power(kW) values need to be summed for 6 entries (5 mins *6 = 30 minutes) successively so index 0-5, index 1-6, 2-7...
and find a maximum in column succ_6 for each month

```
ID  Date_time   load power (kW) succ_6
0   1/01/2018 0:00  0.191566105 1.324208707
1   1/01/2018 0:05  0.193145833 1.341074367
2   1/01/2018 0:10  0.192853152 1.417506192
3   1/01/2018 0:15  0.270974475 1.493065799
4   1/01/2018 0:20  0.290183338 1.508187161
5   1/01/2018 0:25  0.185485805 1.519012164
6   1/01/2018 0:30  0.208431765 1.724022961
7   1/01/2018 0:35  0.269577658 1.922378848
8   1/01/2018 0:40  0.268412758 1.882663692
9   1/01/2018 0:45  0.286095837 1.805121767
10  1/01/2018 0:50  0.301008341 1.70925093
11  1/01/2018 0:55  0.390496602 1.604063424
12  1/01/2018 1:00  0.406787652 1.408709679
13  1/01/2018 1:05  0.229862502 1.192568766
14  1/01/2018 1:10  0.190870833 1.236928491
15  1/01/2018 1:15  0.190224999 1.321553317
```

This has to be done for each month

> e.g 0-5, 1-6,2-7,3-8 ......

I have written an inefficient code, which I think is doing as intended but is taking 36 minutes for one consumer and I need to do it for >100.

```
def monthly_hh_maximum (df_input, filenames,file_path):
    # to store maximum half hourly demand (m_max) for each consumer for each month of year (m_o_y)
    df_m_hh_max =pd.DataFrame(columns=['filename','m_o_y','m_max'])
    # 100 consumers, 100 filenames
    for filename in filenames: 
        print(filename)
        #finds out unique months of year from date in given time series data
        month_o_year=df_input[filename]['Date_conv'].unique()  
        #looping over months of year for one consumer
        for m_o_y in month_o_year:
            # find out the number of days in the given month
            df_input_m_o_y_len=((df_input[filename].loc[df_input[filename]['Date_conv']==m_o_y]))['Date_conv'].size 
            df_temp=df_input[filename].loc[df_input[filename]['Date_conv']==m_o_y]
            print(df_input_m_o_y_len)
            monthly_mm=0 
            for i in range (0,df_input_m_o_y_len-6):
                #Next line retrieves a view of dataframe which has data for that particular
                # month and iteratively sums successive 6 elements of column load power to find the maximum 
                monthly_mm_temp= ((df_input[filename].loc[df_input[filename]['Date_conv']==m_o_y]))['load power (kW)'].iloc[i:i+6].sum()
                print(i)
                print(monthly_mm_temp)
                print(m_o_y)
                if(monthly_mm>monthly_mm_temp):
                    monthly_mm=monthly_mm
                else:
                    monthly_mm=monthly_mm_temp
            df_m_hh_max['filename']=filename
            df_m_hh_max['m_o_y'] = m_o_y
            df_m_hh_max['m_max'] = monthly_mm
```

I am trying to reduce computation time as I have limited resources and I realize that my code is inefficient.

Comment: My apologies, I just did. I didnt realize how it would get pasted. is it readable now?

Comment: This is unreadable. Start with an example source dataframe (5-10 rows is enough). Then explain what you try to do and in the end add an expected output in the form of a dataframe, so we can visually see what you try to do.

Comment: Try using [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html), so something along the lines of `df.rolling('5m').mean()`

Comment: Are you sure you want to *sum* load power? As far as I know, it is not cumulative. I.e. if you use 1 kW for 5min and then 2 kW for 5min you didn't use 3kW for 10min, but 1.5 kW for 10min on average.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, what I am doing is calculating energy consumption from load so 1kW*(5/60)h + 2kW*(5/60)h = 0.24 kWh instead of 3*(10/60) =0.5kWh.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your example is hard to read I assume this is what you are looking for:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': np.random.randint(1, 10, 50)})
df['customer'] = (df.index // (df.shape[0] / 2) + 1).astype(int)
```

The above will create random data for 2 customers. Now the code:

```
rm = df.groupby('customer').value.rolling(6, 1).max()
```

The above will group your data into groups of `6` with minimum `1` occurrence (which you can remove and get `NaN`).

Finally, to add this as column use:

```
df.assign(rolling_max=rm.reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
```

Idea for `max` was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52264091/5811078).

**EDIT**

Given your example, now I'd use this:

```
df['succ_6'] = df['load power (kW)'][::-1].rolling(6, 1).sum()
df.groupby(df['Date_time'].dt.strftime('%B'))['succ_6'].max()

#Date_time
#January    1.922379
#Name: succ_6, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Apologies. Since I need to find a rolling maximum for each month for each consumer, should I group by customer as well as month?

Comment: @ZebaAnjum If each dataset is per customer you can approach it without `groupby`. Otherwise if you have it all in one dataset, you'll need to include user in `groupby`.

Comment: Thanks, but I couldnt get it to work. 1. I dont want rolling window to carry on between months. It needs to start afresh for each month. 2. I want a cascading window with 6 observations, so 0-5, 1-6, 2-7 and so on. This is what worked for me:

Comment: What can be done for a cascading window instead of a rolling one? so summing 0-5, 6-11,12-17 elements?

Answer (score 0):

Using suggestions above from @Dan and @Zipa, here I have a str month column on which I am grouping it by month and then generating the rolling_sum for a cascading window with 6 elements each. Then, again grouping by month and generating max values and then unique values. I am generating all these values for checking results. The final code would be a lot shorter.

```
def demand_a_savings (df_input, filenames,file_path):
    for filename in filenames:
        df_input[filename]['rolling_sum_b'] = df_input[filename].groupby('Month')['load power (kW)'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(6,6).sum())
        df_input[filename]['max_value_b']=df_input[filename].groupby('Month')['rolling_sum_b'].transform(lambda x:x.max())
        print(df_input[filename]['max_value_b'].unique())
```